# why no sequence is created for complexType in WSDL

Tags: java, wsdl

I have some classes which i generate WSDL from, however for a single class the inner content i.e. the fields in the class are not created, the reason is that the java file that is created for that WSDL is empty, like it is skipped.

Can you think about why clientgen wsdl would skip a certain file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, the getters and setters for the fields in the missing sequence MUST have the same wordking, it is case sensitive.